# How to compile two similar header files with my code, in order to run 2 DLLs on it

Tags: c++

I have one of my application written in C++. I have to use two DLLs with this application.

Two Dlls are `MitaiClient.dll` and `MitaiDriver.dll`. For both these DLLs I have lib files and header files. For each DLLs I have one-one header file, but both are with same name `mtai.h`.
The structures declared in both these header files have same name, but their definition is different.

Please suggest how can I compile my code with both these header files so that my application can use both the DLLs simultaneously.

Comment: Work with these headers in different source files.

Comment: @AlexFarber - won't this still violate the one definition rule, as the code is almost the same and if it is in the same (or global) namespace.. I think this will cause linking errors.

Answer (score 0):

So, for example you have **client/mtai.h**

```
#pragma once

struct mtai
{
  int clientData;
};
```

and **driver/mtai.h**

```
#pragma once

struct mtai
{
  int driverdata;
};
```

If you include both of these you'll get an error, as `struct mtai` is defined twice.

To fix this, you can force the includes into their own namespaces like so

```
namespace driver
{
    #include "driver/mtai.h"
}
namespace client
{
    #include "client/mtai.h"
}
```

Then use them within that namespace

e.g

```
client::mtai dataClient;
dataClient.clientData = 42;

driver::mtai dataDriver;
dataDriver.driverdata = 1234;
```

Comment: I also thought about this solution, but I wonder if it will work, because the final exe will be linked at the same time with the 2 DLLs (which are already compiled) and this linking may (and probably will) fail. But it's just a guess.

Comment: It should work, since the names of structs, etc, are just there for the benefit of the programmer - once compiled it all gets stripped away and the code just uses memory addresses.  The dlls are at different memory addresses, and have no reference to each other, so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Are they really stripped or they are mangled (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)? I thought it's the second one, but I may be wrong. I'm kinda new to this.

Comment: They're mangled during compilation, but those mangled names are just used by the compilation process.  When you have `int x; x++` in code, the compiled program doesn't think `now which variable is x?` since the compiled code will just have instructions to increment a given memory address / register value.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Good point. It would be cool, if the OP try it and say about the results. If it works, I'll give you +1.

Comment: It critically depends on how these structs are used. Obviously if there's a `mtai::mtai()` constructor in the DLL, you WILL have name mangling problems. The assertion that name mangling is only done during compilation is flat out wrong. It's done for linking reasons, not so much compilation, and DLL linking is a subset of that.